# Shorter way to get 5 highest and 5 lowest values without changing the stack

Tags: c, max, min

So here is my code . I am trying to find a short way to make this programme work withouth changing any of the arregment.I have been tought the buble way i think its called to arrange a group  from highest to lowest but it clearly say in my given orders not to change the entire group.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int randomInRange (unsigned int min, unsigned int max)
{
     //srand(time(NULL));
  int base_random = rand();
  if (RAND_MAX == base_random) return randomInRange(min, max);
  int range       = max + 1 - min,
      remainder   = RAND_MAX % range,
      bucket      = RAND_MAX / range;
  if (base_random < RAND_MAX - remainder) {
    return min + base_random/bucket;
  } else {
    return randomInRange (min, max);
  }
}

int main()
{
    int ari,i,min,max;
    printf("Gi'me length of the group")
    scanf("%d",&ari);
    int pinakas[ari];
    printf("Gi'me lowest and highest values");
    scanf("%d",&min);
    scanf("%d",&max);
    for(i = 0; i < ari; i++)
    {
        pinakas[ari] = randomInRange(min,max);
    }
    int el,meg,c;
    el = max+1;
    meg = min-1;
    c = 0;
    printf("Highest   Lowest");
    while( c != 4;)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < ari; i++)
        {
            if(el > pinakas[ari])
            {
                el = pinakas[ari];
            }
            if( meg < pinakas[ari])
            {
                meg = pinakas[ari];
            }
            if(i == 4)
            {
                printf("%d   %d",el,meg);
              ( is there something that i can put here is order to make el,meg to go for the second lowest ,second highest? and so on till i get the 5 highest and 5 lowests.Keep in mind the the lowest length of my group will be pinakas[5].) 
            }
        }
        c++;
     }
```

Comment: This is wrong: `pinakas[ari] = randomInRange(min,max);` -you are iterating `i` not `ari` in this loop.  It looks like this error was made in other places as well.

Comment: You can greatly simplify your `randomInRange()` function — which is good because it avoids the bias caused by the range of value not being a multiple of RAND_MAX. I use a simple iterative function: `size_t RandomInteger(size_t lo, size_t hi)
{
    assert(hi > lo);
    size_t range = hi - lo + 1;
    size_t max_r = RAND_MAX - (RAND_MAX % range);
    size_t r;
    while ((r = rand()) > max_r)
        ;
    r = (r % range + lo);
    assert(lo <= r && r <= hi);
    return r;
}` and I've checked that both `lo` and `hi` are selected on occasion (which is the behaviour I want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each item in the array, up to 5 comparisons are done for the min list and 5 for the max list.
Suggest calling a function to do this in a tidy fashion.

```
#include<assert.h>

// `list` is `const` as OP says "withouth changing any of the arregment".
void sort_ends(const int *list, size_t listlen, int *minlist, int *maxlist, 
    size_t mlen) {
  assert(list);
  assert(minlist);
  assert(maxlist);
  assert(mlen >= 1);
  assert(listlen >= mlen);

  minlist[0] = list[0];
  // For each element after the first ...
  for (size_t i = 1; i < listlen; i++) {
    int mincandidate = list[i];
    size_t mini = i;
    if (mini > mlen) mini = mlen;
    do {
      mini--;
      if (mincandidate >= minlist[mini]) 
        break;
      // swap mincandidate and minlist[mini]
      int t = mincandidate;
      mincandidate =  minlist[mini];
      minlist[mini] = t;
    } while (mini > 0);
  }
  // Do similar for maxlist, left for OP
}

int main() {
  int ari;
  // ...
  int pinakas[ari];
  // ...
  int mlen = 5;
  int minlist[mlen];
  int maxlist[mlen];
  sort_ends(pinakas, ari, minlist, maxlist, mlen);
  return 0;
}
```

Alternative approach, find min index and then `memove()`.